# Rails: show duplicate when validating uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, custom-errors

I have a Rails model that validates its slugs are unique, like so:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :slug
```

I'm getting lots of validation failures during a bulk import, and have a screen of errors like this:

```
ERROR: invalid () - Validation failed: Slug has already been taken
ERROR: invalid () - Validation failed: Slug has already been taken
ERROR: invalid () - Validation failed: Slug has already been taken
...
```

I'd like to have the error messages show which slugs are failing validation. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
validates :slug, uniqueness: { message: "%{value} has already been taken" }
```

If this is in a log though I think you're going to write a custom validation and log it there.